# Kotlin Multiplatform library unresolved dependency at runtime

Tags: gradle, dependencies, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm making a private Kotlin Multiplatform library that will be in a private repo hosted on Bitbucket.

My library depends on another library, called Krypto.

So, naturally, I have the following dependency in the common module of the library:

```
val commonMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        api("com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto:2.2.0")
    }
}
```

Now, when I import the library via Cocoapods to an iOS project, it works perfectly fine. However when I insert the .jar file to my Android project as a dependency:

```
implementation files('libs/MyLibrary-jvm-1.0.0.jar')
```

it compiles, but at runtime crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/soywiz/krypto/SHA256Kt
```

If I add the Krypto dependency to my Android project, everything works fine, however I would like the dependencies to be already included in my library. How to do that?

I also tried adding the java-library plugin and adding the dependency in a java build block, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the documentation all along... https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries

In the Gradle configuration of the binaries of a specific platform we need to  use **export()** to include dependencies. To also include dependencies of the dependencies, we need to do **export(dep, transitiveExport = true)**.

```kotlin
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api(project(":dependency"))
            }
        }
    }
    java().binaries {
        framework {
            export(project(":dependency"), transitiveExport = true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you solve this because I get an error when calling ```java().binaries {```

Comment: @box what error?

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by publishing the library as a local maven library :)